# Loading failed Error: TypeError: require is not a function(…)

Tags: angular, typescript, momentjs

I am trying to implement the very basic example of momentjs in typescript

i am getting error as
[enter image description here][1]
My app.ts

```
import {NgModule, Component} from '@angular/core';
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {platformBrowserDynamic} from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import {MomentModule} from 'angular2-moment/moment.module';

@Component({
    selector: 'timeago-demo'
    template: `

     {{moment}}

    `
})
class TimeagoDemoComponent {

    moment('2015').weekdayCalc([1,2]); //104  
    moment('2015').isoWeekdayCalc([1,2]); //104
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    MomentModule
  ],
  declarations: [ TimeagoDemoComponent ]
  bootstrap: [ TimeagoDemoComponent ]
})
class TimeagoDemoModule {}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(TimeagoDemoModule);
```

i want the no of days in a week... and week in the month
i refer the link as

1. https://www.npmjs.com/package/moment-weekday-calc

Comment: You need to edit your question correctly.. where is the error?

Comment: Why did you keep `require('moment-business-days')` in your class?

Comment: @suraj:- when i run the code i am just getting an loading.. when i check the by inspect it shows me  Loading failed Error: TypeError: require is not a function(…).................@Any Name:- i did'nt put it anywhere sir

Comment: As @AnyName asked, why do you need `require`? you should `import` it

Comment: @SD991 Seriously? You didn't even read your code? It is right inside `class TimeagoDemoComponent`

Comment: remove this from your component `var moment = require('moment-business-days');`

Comment: i am so confused with many articals.. can you please tell how to do that.. means no of days in week and no of weeks in a month

Comment: And the library you have installed is for been used by PIPE. I don't think you can achieve what you want using this library. It's more for format date in template

Comment: i have updated my code please have a look